# Should I connect "line" to "line" and "neutral" to "neutral" on my power supply

Tags: power-supply, plug, line

I have an industrial power supplyy that I use in a device I am making. I am attaching a picture of it. It has "line", "neutral" and "ground" input connections. Ground is ok. But I don't know if I should be careful to connect "line" of my AC plug to "line" input of the power supply.

We use German type plugs here in Turkey:

[image: photo]

As you can see you can connect these German type plugs whatever way you want. So line might become neutral and neutral might become line depending on the direction you inserted the plug.

What should I do? Is it ok and safe to use German plugs with this power supply? Are there special power supplies where switching line and neutral inputs doesn't matter?

[image: power supply]

Comment: Is the power supply CE marked and if so is it approved for sale in your country? If not CE marked or if not approved for your country you are obliged to satisfy yourself (and your end user/customer) that is is safe. Either way you need documents from the supplier enabling you to use it or CE mark it. That's for EU - I don't know how this applies to Turkey (yet?). Having said all of that I find it hard to envisage a power supply like this not being able to be connected L-N and N-L.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of "German" type plug you can never be sure which way the plug is inserted. This implies that your electrical mains is not built to distinguish between Live and Neutral, in other words the Neutral is connected to ground somewhere before it enters your house. As long as your device isn't relying on Neutral being uncharged at no-load conditions, it should not matter how you connect L and N.